# Search button not clickable on its whole area

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, search

I'm using Firefox 18.0.1. If I go to [the search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search), the search button is not clickable on its whole area. It can only be clicked (and the cursor is only shown as a hand) on the left half of the search button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a simple CSS bug in the firefox layout, fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 5):

Confirmed; in Firefox `<div id="sidebar">` is on top of the button, as the search bar itself is located *next* to the title "Search", rather than underneath it. No problem in my Chrome:

[image] [image]